# mysql jdbc connection issues in RHEL 6

Tags: mysql, java, mysql-connection

I have setup the `mysql` database in one of the RHEL 6 servers. I would like to connect to this server's database from any other machine using a `java` program. How should I do it?

Comment: what part of this Q & A is specific to RHEL?

Comment: @1_CR, the mysql configuration file location is specific to RHEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setting class path**

The JDBC connector will be located in the path `/usr/share/java/`. We can export the *classpath* as,

```
export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

**Grant privileges to user**

For the user connecting to the database, the privileges should be granted. This can be achieved using the below `mysql` query.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘user’@’%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘<user-password>’ WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Now, we can establish a connection to this machine's `mysql` server using the java program but only as a `localhost`. If we need to use this server's name or connect from some other machine, we will get several exceptions as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835800/jdbc-mysql-communications-link-failure-to-remote-database) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358).

**Edit `/etc/hosts` file**

It is to be noted that in the above step if I just used the IP address of the machine rather than the hostname of the machine, it worked. So, I suspected the issue was something related to `dns` name resolution.

I modified my `/etc/hosts` file to have the below entry.

```
127.0.0.1   servername.edu        localhost
```

I was still not able to connect to the database using the hostname which I thought was pretty weird given that I have changed the `/etc/hosts` file as well. I even stopped `ip6tables` to check if that is the issue. However, none of the options worked and it was giving me the exception as,

```
ERROR: java.net.UnknownHostException:connection refused
```

**Edit /etc/my.cnf file**

The last exception was promising. It says connection refused rather than saying something like not able to resolve the hostname. So, I thought something should be changed in the `/etc/my.cnf` file and I added the below lines to the file.

```
port=3306
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

When I made the above changes, I could connect to this machine from anywhere using the hostname.